# Fill DataGridView data from SQL table and populate a GridView ComboBox from a different SQL Server table

Tags: c#

I have a `DataGridView` on a form that get it records from SQL Server table, I have a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in the `DataGridView` that populates its data from a different SQL Server table. Now I want to use the record from `table2(ComboBox table)` to fill table 1. 
Its a Windows Application

```
//to fill the grid
private void gridViewFillAddress()
{
    //dataGridViewCashbook.DataSource = EmployeeDataAccessLayer.GetAllEmployees();
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = HP\SQL; Initial Catalog = Simpca; Integrated Security = True");
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM ADDRESSBOOKNEW";
    SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, myConnection);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
    DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
    dgvAdressBook.DataSource = dbdataset;
    sda.Update(dbdataset);
    dgvAdressBook.Columns["DateAddress"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/mm/dd";
}
//to fill the combo
void fillBANKERS()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = HP\SQL; Initial Catalog = Simpca; Integrated Security = True");
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM BANKLIST;";
    SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
    DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
    BANK.ValueMember = "BANKLISTNAME";
    BANK.DisplayMember = "BANKLISTNAME";
    DataRow topItem = dbdataset.NewRow();
    topItem[0] = "0";
    topItem[1] = "";
    dbdataset.Rows.InsertAt(topItem, 0);
    BANK.DataSource = dbdataset;
}
```

This is my code

```
private void dgvAdressBook_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //to insert and modify           
     if (dgvAdressBook.CurrentRow != null)
     {
         SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Sourc = HP\SQL; Initial Catalog = Simpca; Integrated Security = True");
         myConnection.Open();
         DataGridViewRow dgvRow = dgvAdressBook.CurrentRow;
         SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand("EditAddAddressBook", myConnection);
         cmdDataBase.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         if (dgvRow.Cells["id"].Value == DBNull.Value)
             cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
         else 
             cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(dgvRow.Cells["id"].Value));
         cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dgvRow.Cells["NAME"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "": dgvRow.Cells["NAME"].Value.ToString());
         cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACCTNUMBERPAYEE", dgvRow.Cells["ACCTNUMBER"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "0" : dgvRow.Cells["ACCTNUMBER"].Value.ToString());                 
         //The Combo Box 
         cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BANKERS", dgvRow.Cells["BANKERS"].Value == DBNull.Value ?  "" : dgvRow.Cells["BANKERS"].Value.ToString());
         cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SORTCODE", Convert.ToInt32(dgvRow.Cells["SORT"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "0" : dgvRow.Cells["SORT"].Value));
         cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I expect the combobox column to fill the existing records in table1 for bankers but it return blank until I select the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

use Itemdatabound event like below

```
protected void dgvAdressBook_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_ClientDetail.Rows)
        {
          DataGridViewComboBoxCell BankersCombo = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells[index of BankersCombo column]);

          BankersCombo.DataSource = // your contacts datasource;
          BankersCombo.DisplayMember = "name of field to be displayed like say ContactName";
          BankersCombo.ValueMember = "Id";
        }
}
```

Comment: I have checked the list of events available for the DataGridView, i cant find ItemDataBound. i am using windows application.

Comment: In winforms you have to use something like this , the above will work for webforms.      https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/combobox-with-datagridview-in-c/